# Why does this even compile?

Tags: typescript, typechecking

```
class X {}
let x : X = 123 // why is this ok?
console.log(x instanceof X)
```

The above code compiles (for some reason) and yields `false`.

Please explain to me why TypeScript does not enforce type-correctness in this case.

**Edit for future readers**:

Murat K's answer is correct but I'd like to save you a click and 15 minutes of your time:

- TypeScript's type system is structural.
- `123` is being treated as an object of type `Number`.
- Structurally speaking, `Number` is <strike>a subtype</strike> type-compatible to `X` because it has all the methods and fields of `X` and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty class is basically an empty object since it has nothing to classify as something. That's why you can assign to it anything.

See the github issue for the same question [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5451)